# Select Custom Attribute from nested LI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu item that looks like the below, now in this case i have a parent with a `groupId=5` which is Analytics. Now what i am trying to-do is when i click on an LI i want to select the `link-id` ... now i got that to work easily.

No the problem comes in, how can i select `link-id="22"` and `link-id="23"`
without triggering `link-id=21` because in this case `link-id=21` is another sub menu.

***HTML***

```
<li groupid="5">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                    <span class="nav-label">Analytics</span>
                    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul sub-groupid="5" class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li link-id="13"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li link-id="19"><a href="#">Social Report Card</a></li>
                    <li link-id="20">@Html.ActionLink("Reputation Report Card", "ReputationReportCard", "Reports", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                    <li link-id="21">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-label">Facebook Snapshot</span>
                            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                            <li link-id="22">@Html.ActionLink("Overview", "Index", "Overview", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                            <li link-id="23">@Html.ActionLink("Content", "Index", "Content", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

***SELECT LINK***

```
   $("ul[sub-groupid] > li").click(function (e) {
        NavigationMenu.App.SetLinkId($(this).attr('link-id'));
    });
```

So in a nutshell, i want to be able to select the `link-id` but if the `link-id` has a submenu, i want to select the submenu's link-id

Comment: what if you click on `Facebook Snapshot`

Comment: I suggest to use `$("ul[sub-groupid] li")` instead of `$("ul[sub-groupid] > li")` and try..

Comment: Use `$("li[link-id]")` . It will target all li with 'link-id' attribute

Comment: if you click on the Facebook snapshot it, slide down the nav-third-level with the other 2 link in

Comment: @GuruprasadRao and Joshua, trying your guys suggestions now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a click handler for the `[sub-groupid]` element, then find the closest `li` to the clicked element and then get its `link-id`

```js
$("ul[sub-groupid]").click(function(e) {
  alert($(e.target).closest('li[link-id]').attr('link-id'));
  NavigationMenu.App.SetLinkId($(e.target).closest('li[link-id]').attr('link-id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li groupid="5">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
      <span class="nav-label">Analytics</span>
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul sub-groupid="5" class="nav nav-second-level">
      <li link-id="13"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li link-id="19"><a href="#">Social Report Card</a></li>
      <li link-id="20">@Html.ActionLink("Reputation Report Card", "ReputationReportCard", "Reports", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
      <li link-id="21">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="nav-label">Facebook Snapshot</span>
          <span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
          <li link-id="22">@Html.ActionLink("Overview", "Index", "Overview", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
          <li link-id="23">@Html.ActionLink("Content", "Index", "Content", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use it:

```
$("ul[sub-groupid] li").click(function (e) {
    var lid = $(this).has('ul') 
              ? $(this).find('li').attr('link-id') 
              : $(this).attr('link-id');
    NavigationMenu.App.SetLinkId(lid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("ul[sub-groupid] li").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).attr('link-id'))
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li groupid="5">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                    <span class="nav-label">Analytics</span>
                    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul sub-groupid="5" class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li link-id="13"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li link-id="19"><a href="#">Social Report Card</a></li>
                    <li link-id="20">@Html.ActionLink("Reputation Report Card", "ReputationReportCard", "Reports", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                    <li link-id="21">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-label">Facebook Snapshot</span>
                            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                            <li link-id="22">@Html.ActionLink("Overview", "Index", "Overview", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                            <li link-id="23">@Html.ActionLink("Content", "Index", "Content", new { area = "Analytics" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```